# Provisioning state blank when creating Backend Address Pool

Tags: azure, powershell

I am running the following commands to try and create a new Backend Address Pool in Azure's Application Gateway service.

```
$NewBackendPool = New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -Name "MHA-DEVOPS-TEST-2" -BackendFqdns "test.com"
Write-Host "Provisioning state: $($NewBackendPool.ProvisioningState)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
$NewBackendPool
```

The output I get is as follows:

[image: Output]

I receive no error, but the `ProvisioningState` value is blank and when I try to attach this to my Application Gateway using the `Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool`, nothing fails but the Backend Address Pool is definitely not created/attached.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, it will work fine.

```
$AppGw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "<Your ApplicationGateway Name>" -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>"
$AppGw = Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name "test11" -BackendFqdns "test11.com"
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
```

Result snippet:

[image]

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Trying this now, thank you. If this works.. what exactly is the `New-` variant of this command meant to do?

Comment: @dunc Not sure, may be just create a new pool in the powershell session, not assign to any application gateway,  for your case, it seems to be unnecessary to use it. The most important command is `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway` .

Comment: That's the bit I was missing, yeah. Working now Joy, thank you!

Comment: @dunc Glad to hear that!

Comment: If you've got a few minutes to spare @Joy, my latest question is something you can probably answer really easily too - but I can't get my head round it!